# Copy directory from another branch

Tags: git

There is a question "[Git: copy all files in a directory from another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668886/git-copy-all-files-in-a-directory-from-another-branch)" which shows how. But it doesn't delete files that are in the current branch, but that are deleted in the other branch.

There are few solutions I usually use:

1. Delete the directory locally `rm -r dir`, then do `git checkout otherBranch -- dir`. It works, but is slow for large directories.
2. `git checkout dir` and then `git rm $(git diff --name-only otherBranch -- dir)`. It works, but I think there should be a better solution.

Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: I don't know any other method, but I'm curious: have you tried running a benchmark to find out how the two approaches fare on, say, the `github.com/git/git` repository?

Comment: @Jubobs I bet second option will be faster, but may fail if `diff` would return too large list. Also it would fail if file names have spaces or special chars.

Comment: What you're describing comes up more in testing/build/QA.  If the idea is to switch frequently between a small number of directory states (i.e. branches), you should have all the states on the filesystem and just symlink the one you want.  The result is instantaneous.

Comment: @JoeAtzberger No, sometimes I do it when I want revert a directory back to a different revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git reset otherBranch -- dir
git clean -df
git checkout .
```

This should update the contents of dir with those of the same directory on the other branch.

Comment: WARNING: It deletes your uncommitted files