# Restore deleted folder in Git correctly so files end up in current branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I need to restore a folder I deleted in Git but I am having trouble doing it so I end up with the folder in the correct branch.

I have done:

```
git checkout commit_id -- /path/to/folder
```

This just puts the repo in a *detached HEAD* state and I am unsure how to get the files back to the *master* branch?

I also tried:

```
git checkout -b restore commit_id -- /path/to/folder
```

This created a new branch, but when I tried to merge that branch into *master* it said it was "Already up to date".

Running the below didn't work either as per the apparent duplicate question, this simply switched me to the other branch again:

```
git checkout myBranch -- /path/to/folder
```

Why is this so hard to do? What is the correct way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: copy all files in a directory from another branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668886/git-copy-all-files-in-a-directory-from-another-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first try should work. A working example:

```
▸ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/***/Desktop/repo/.git/

▸ mkdir foo
▸ echo "foo" > foo/1
▸ git add foo
▸ git commit -m "file in foo"

▸ echo "bar" > 1
▸ git add .
▸ git commit -m "file"

▸ rm -rd foo
▸ git add foo
▸ git commit -m "removed foo"

▸ echo "foobar" >> 1
▸ git add .
▸ git commit -m "change"
```

The tree now looks like this:

```
* 95e470d (HEAD -> master) change
* e644860 removed foo
* 35e2e02 file
* 16fd6f0 file in foo

▸ git checkout HEAD~2 -- ./foo/
```

Results in:

```
▸ git status

    new file:   foo/1
```

I figure maybe the path put in is wrong. When I would do `git checkout HEAD~2 -- foo`, nothing happens. Try to use a relative path starting with `./`.

Comment: That did it thanks. I was doing it as just the folder name, but once I added `./` to the start of the folder name like `git checkout commit_id -- ./folder_name` it worked.