# Git make new branch and overwrite it with code from GitHub

Tags: git, github, branch, overwrite, pull

I am studying a book about TDD, and in an appendix, they ask us to use code which is given in a GitHub branch. I know I can make a new folder, do `git init`, and use `git pull`, but it would be easier to have a separate branch and have a branch from GitHub there. Could you advise me on how I can take code and history from a branch in GitHub, and make that the code and history of a new branch in my local repo? I have created the branch using `git checkout -b new_branch`. Now, if I use `git pull`, it shows me merge errors, because my branch and the code from GitHub has some substantial differences.

**Note**: I still haven't added an origin. I just commit to my local repo, and none of my code is on GitHub.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you’re creating a repository for your various projects etc while studying, right? Why don’t you just make separate folders within the same repo? This would let you copy down the files themselves from the branch, without causing any conflicts.

Comment: Good idea, but is there a way to do this without manually downloading? I want to know if it is possible using Git.

Comment: This isn’t what git is intended for so there isn’t a clean way to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668886/git-copy-all-files-in-a-directory-from-another-branch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a branch without any history, you can use `git checkout --orphan YOUR_NEW_BRANCH` ([git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt)).

You'll then have a new branch that contains all the files that were in the initial branch, which you'll now need to delete using `git rm -rf .` ([In git, is there a simple way of introducing an unrelated branch to a repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1384325/4722345)).

You can then use `git pull URL THEIR_BRANCH` to pull down their branch.

Comment: git pull URL BRANCH

Comment: It gives me an error saying that please commit your changes or stash them. If I revert my changes and do `git pull`, it's saying something about 'FETCH HEAD'. Not an error, I think it's saying that 'FETCH HEAD' is at the branch from GitHub. But my code doesn't have any changes.

Comment: Oh sorry I meant that you would create a new branch. Updated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it's saying the thing specified in the last comment. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Sorry I didn't actually test it out. I see the problem - try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below command

```
git checkout -b <new-branch> <commit-id>/<branch>
```

Comment: I want to take it from GitHub, not from a local commit. Is that possible?