# Copying a directory from the master branch into an empty orphaned branch?

Tags: git

I'm trying to copy the `projects/slice/src/lib/` folder from the `master` branch of [this project](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/slice) into an empty orphaned `lib` branch.

The directory structure `projects/slice/src/lib/` should be mirrored in both branches.

This is how I'm attempting to go about it based on the answer for [copying over a branch directory here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668886/git-copy-all-files-in-a-directory-from-another-branch).

```
% git clone git@github.com:fireflysemantics/slice.git
% cd slice
% git switch --orphan lib
% git checkout master -- projects/slice/src/lib/
% git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
```

So after I attempt the copy with `git checkout master -- projects/slice/src/lib/` it still shows me as being on the `master` branch with everything being up to date.

How do we copy `lib` folder into the new empty `lib` branch?

Comment: Are you expecting the `lib` folder to be empty?

Comment: The `lib` folder in the master branch has all the Angular Library files in it...in the master branch ... and after I attempt the copy it seems I'm still in the `master` branch and the `lib` branch is still empty ... so it's like the ocpy never took place ...

Comment: Why not use cherry pick, and then restore everything else? `git cherry-pick -n master; git restore <list-of-directories-not-lib>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
touch f && git add . && git commit -m "M" && git rm f && git add . && git commit -m "M"
```

It creates a temporary file `f` and commits it.  It's necessary to do this in order to get the `lib` branch to exist.

After that the last commit can be removed with `git reset --hard HEAD^` if we want to minimize the commit history.

The folder `projects/slice/src/lib/` can now be copied in to the `lib` branch.

```
git checkout master -- projects/slice/src/lib/
```