# Git removing the last N commits?

Tags: git, macos, github

[According to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153486/how-to-delete-the-last-n-commits-on-github-and-locally) we should be able to remove the last N commits like this (Example uses 2 commits):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
or
git reset --hard HEAD^^
```

However when I try this it produces this error (This is a complete rundown):

```
 % touch f && git add . && git commit -m "M"
[master (root-commit) fc2ff7f] M
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 f
 % touch f2 && git add . && git commit -m "M"
[master 6017bff] M
1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 f2
 % git log
commit 6017bff2f76fe15e6e7c99e3d386ef12db4d3ffb (HEAD -> master)
Author: Ole Ersoy <ole.ersoy@gmail.com>
Date: Wed Dec 6 14:17:11 2023 -0500

    M

commit fc2ff7fc92eebb6c7384d9887faf9c608c891ae0
Author: Ole Ersoy <ole.ersoy@gmail.com>
Date: Wed Dec 6 14:17:06 2023 -0500

    M

 % git reset --hard HEAD^^
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is `^` an escape-code for your terminal? Does `HEAD~2` work?

Comment: Also, seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: You only have two commits and you HEAD is pointing to the last one and know you are trying to go back 2 commits before head, which is not possible.

Comment: Neither `HEAD~2` or `HEAD^^` work ...

Comment: @Cyclonecode OK I see what you mean ... In order to remove the last 2 commits there has to be at least 3 commits ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reset to an empty git repository. You must have at least 3 commits in your repository in order to remove two commits.

Add one more commit and then try either command again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have two commits you cannot reset two commits back from head. One way would be to remove the first commit would be to create a temporary branch:

```
# checkout an orphan branch from master
git checkout --orphan tmp
# at this point their is no history
git log --oneline
> fatal: your current branch 'tmp' does not have any commits yet

# add a first commit and make tmp the master branch
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git branch -M master
git log --oneline                                                                                  
> d390ffe (HEAD -> master) Initial commit
```

Comment: Or if you really wanted an empty repository you could just `rm -r .git` and `git init` again....

Comment: @DavidT  I really wanted an empty orphan branch, but it seems we need at least one commit in order for the branch to exist ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586571/copying-a-directory-from-the-master-branch-into-an-empty-orphaned-branch

Comment: @DavidT `rm -r .git` removes too much. It removes config (remotes, local aliases) and hooks.

Comment: @phd I question how many people are going to have all that defined on a repository with no commits....  To say that another way I there are times I want an empty repo and every time I just blow away the .git folder.

Comment: @Ole you can create as many empty orphan branches as you want with `git checkout --orphan annie`, however unless you commit something there is no reason to store anything in the history (since all empty branches are identical) - behind the scenes the command above just updates the file `.git/HEAD` hence there will only ever be one orphan branch active at any time.

Comment: @DavidT Well, I consider that bad practice anyway so I want to warn users to think twice before doing destructive `rm`. What you do is up to you, sure.